# MonoTouch - how to override static UIView.layerClass

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, static-methods

I'm trying to port [AUISelectiveBordersView](https://github.com/adam-siton/AUISelectiveBordersView) to MonoTouch.
It's basically a subclass of `CALayer` and integration in `UIView` via Categories.

"Translation" of AUISelectiveBordersLayer is easy, but integration point is a bit tricky. In obj-c it's done like:

```
@implementation UIView (AUISelectiveBorder)

+(Class) layerClass {
    return [AUISelectiveBordersLayer class];
}
```

Is there any way to translate this to MonoTouch? It looks like overriding a static method, but I don't see anything like `layerClass` or `layerType` in MT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately I found that it works via subclassing UIView:

```
public class UIViewWithSelectiveBorders : UIView {

    [Export("layerClass")]
    public static Class LayerClass () {
        return new Class (typeof(SelectiveBorderLayer));
    }
}
```

At the moment that's enough for my tasks, but a more general question is still actual: is there a way to change that without subclassing `UIView` (for example, if I want to override that for all `UILabel`s)

Comment: There is a way. But it involves more work than just subclassing UILabel. The way you do it above is minimal.

Comment: Could you please give a link to that way? I'm very interested in case it'll be needed in coming tasks

Comment: Can you help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174025/monotouch-how-to-override-static-uicollectionviewlayout-layoutattributesclass