# MonoTouch - how to override static UICollectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesClass

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, xamarin, uicollectionviewlayout

I have the opposite  problem to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487271/monotouch-how-to-override-static-uiview-layerclass)

Unlike UIView, where monotouch has omitted the definition of the static method layerClass, presumedly to allow you to define it in a subclass, layoutAttributesClass is defined in UICollectionViewLayout and I have no idea how to override it in my subclass.

I've tried...

```
    [Export ("layoutAttributesClass")]
    public static Class LayoutAttributesClass {
        get { return new Class(typeof(MyClass)); }
    }
```

... but this is never called.

Comment: This should work. Can you file a bug with a test case here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com?

Comment: Done - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10877, should LayoutAttributesClass have been omitted from UICollectionViewLayout to allow implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This actually works, don't let the hides inherited member warning throw you off (like I did) -you can use the new operator to get rid of it and it still works.

The real problem if you go down this route is implementing copyWithZone on your UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes subclass as support for this is fairly lacking in Xamarin

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes/CircleLayout.cs) it is shown how `layoutAttributesClass` should be defined. It is the same as yours except of a `new` operator. Also the `copyWithZone` is shown there.